# Time functions / methods with parameters via timeit: a simple & short workaround

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, time, lambda

I guess we've all seen `timeit` failing with something like`ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable` when trying use timeit with a custom function/method and passing parameters to it.

E.g.

```
1> import timeit         
2>                       
3> def testing(a):       
4>     for i in range(0, 1000):
5>         a + 1     
6>                       
7> print (timeit.timeit(testing(5), number=1000))
```

Would fail with `ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable` as it is unable to locate without further setups/imports (which messes the statement up, in my opinion).

So, the question that remains is: What is a small, minimalistic (perhaps even "pythonic") way to deal with the problem?

How can we easily time a code snippet for measuring the execution time with all benefits of pythons `timeit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer I found out (and in my mind a nice one) is to wrap the function you want to call into another parameterless function. Of course this would create a little overhead and mess up readability...that is why lambdas are a nice workaround for this little hack:

```
1> import timeit               
2>                             
3> def testing(a):             
4>     for i in range(0, 1000):
5>         a + 1           
6>                             
7> print (timeit.timeit(lambda: testing(5), number=1000))

Output> 0.0097241420746
```

The only change we mad is in line 7: instead of calling *testing* directly we wrap it with a lambda function. Now *timeit* do not has to worry about unknown parameters, because it gets a clean, wrapped anonymous function passed.

Another benefit is this **is working in both**, **python 2.7.X and python 3.X**, without any changes :)

Comment: So what approach would *not* work across Python 2.7 and 3.x without changes?

Comment: Of course I did not try any possible solution. Hence I am not sure which would work on 2.7.X or 3.X only...but it is not uncommon that a lot of code snippets are not cross-compatible (or, at least, do not produce the same result). I just thought it would be nice to mention that this solutions works in both versions and delivers the same results.

Answer (score 3):

Put the code snippet in a string, and add an import statement to the setup (also a string):

```
print(timeit.timeit('testing(5)', 'from __main__ import testing', number=1000))
```

The script is always called `__main__`.

As of Python 2.6, both the statement and the setup parameters take a function with no parameters, so you can wrap the `testing(5)` call in a lambda or simple function. Take into account that this takes *extra overhead* to run; from the [`timeit.Timer()` class documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer):

> The *stmt* and *setup* parameters can also take objects that are callable without arguments. This will embed calls to them in a timer function that will then be executed by `timeit()`. **Note that the timing overhead is a little larger in this case because of the extra function calls.**

Take this into account when comparing different approaches, don't mix the two styles.